# How to prevent app A to inform about app B existence?

Tags: applications

I've two apps, A & B.
When I start app A, it prompts me with a message: 
"Please remove app B to continue!"
How can I prevent app A from reading the installed apps list.
Or is there a way to rename app B to something else?

App A is a taxi app like Ubber.
App B is the Waze.

Comment: Use APK Editor to change app B's package name.

Comment: I've Changed the waze package name from com.waze  to com.ways, but after installing the new apk, all I see is force close!

Comment: Similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/186771/96277. No answers though.