# How to prevent an application from getting installed apps

Tags: applications, permissions

I'm a android user not a developer and just want to know how can I prevent an app e.g. Facebook from getting installed apps list? 
Or alternatively hide some apps from installed list in order to fool the Facebook app.

Comment: XPrivacy can do this but it works well only for Android 6.0.1 and below, and requires a rooted device with Xposed Framework.